# Sequential spectra formed from applications of B

Tags: homotopy-theory, spectra

I am interested in the Ω-spectrum Xᵢ, Xᵢ ≅ $ΩX_{i+1}$, where $Xᵢ := BⁿX$ for a CW-complex $X$. This construction is left adjoint, right?

It seemed like it wouldn't be very hard to construct the smash product of two Ω-spectra, especially since smash product is supposed to be left adjoint to hom. I've been told that it is either difficult or impossible to construct a functorial smash product for Ω-spectra, which is one of the selling points of other models.

It's well known that there isn't a category of spectra with a [certain five] [1](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271593/1-s2.0-S0022404900X03209/1-s2.0-0022404991900306/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEH4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIHyCCpxJmYWuFYeeszB5Vwi41evHS1T2%2BqN8Fi%2FPHBuhAiBGXb9dKUXz3VgDlFN0RqrUvBbFo%2BXBpQOq%2F8EGxWP09iqzBQhmEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMRuQgKhycXMrezQbwKpAFhrmzXVYK4dEa0LaUzZbcCgbi9TfnIIKYorOWhhCryscjYMyON8jvv2TqR3rUVB4kflga3SaHQQJqXXTOxMhDETe0oR6pMZu1QeLxjVeJnsip9I4UXquaiu%2FzUi%2BotFEw%2FKuOaBHUDgSl%2Fkos9BXR6p7eL3TF9XB%2BHuD9u5onr%2BP7eezlzF3mA12ryv6MYFPbZ1BYGKfivYQdfr2hs65E%2BuRnmdNrCnds%2B%2F8KIWlEBWLkLHy2hnN7X3rcYhT34AGnc6RkOF%2Fre%2FrEioayyUODY8bwLPpshg7q0OgbsjlFOSCyQ%2Ba8nFV8CcWV6DnaJpAC7lt8NOZd6OEFDyJaalxa6mwMZdkHCa%2B4BBkfnMyhQZy%2BCvVPhpkivuvQwu91OfREAS4AR9j3cxtm7k1FFmJSaOAtxPpEskEx8KG25TtdaHurFLjrCD8g8VSZb5Yeuv%2BtbtzLQZIJxFMscFFhHCUdCyZmSzloCTlk7xrmEexKFF4FXFIuhJ1Twc53ZpoKW6IoKY3GSEZdMioPrMJdYsHJ9E1Tk%2BHnymFny6LxCHxUhMagK9ubEa%2BFD3sxPJoQe8Mmb0szSoBSlTbac%2BrZ3BAFHw8t7Et2sx3E9Jc630qH3UeF94x4FQvjjD8pzEA5ROlOObBwB4GCH5uO26brqSertYYmUg3KMIdNByQKHZG3F0Y0UTncjzNoNmVoefXup6yCWqtjZiRPkGMVZ9d3bAij4nzP0PCpQQAgXG2FPeB%2BbPtS89QcIS00Klbg%2F84L1z8HlhxWGl2%2FAvxdJoVBVcLVZdgs79RyWASJcm8F94etv9k95wtZBBvMkirqo6JO8Qwp9jj28e9JfMXRgk0iKyMm372yn0pQZwvbpQGBvmHSVoEw75WTqAY6sgH0Csc4ck5%2BsTKdYN80F%2BO1MGkhDZfzEPA689%2BM7SDej6HYDO5%2F50VBglrpvUAlRB%2F3xhOPaeuqk%2BMHXR%2Fz1ry%2Fjpi7E5p1oB9yP85FOylDYXKu22ixKlPfzqWdb5WfEFElp7lJfibc1dkxgk%2BnMf6GatRwB%2F8jRtVDUbdx6LQ8%2BS%2BaLpPzXj7TlaCTt5wIwao24q7GCGBvYCMUuIOAjCvllFCH6UEvFnNYI8tDy5mrvr1i&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230915T224444Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYX3BP5B26%2F20230915%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e4cd3f309413e5b1375b49447fdef0985a1f0aec9880eea63328ace333ab5a54&hash=950dcf1bb81b612707e10060da0a116476552ca9d7ef6496e5ca0d562477698a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0022404991900306&tid=spdf-4762ff18-7098-4812-9c1a-9a15fd2bd8cb&sid=e2fb9c2842b9974ecf989af9bf737064f678gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f1559565355545a5701&rr=8074655ecfd71130&cc=us) properties. But this construction with B suggested a different unit.

The construction bears similarities with localization, where we have this:

- Let R be a ring and let x : R be an element. $R[x^{-1}]$ is an R-algebra in which $x$ has an inverse. For each $R$-algebra $S$ in which $x$ is invertible, there is a unique map $R[x^{-1}] ⭢ S$ which produces a commutative triangle.

My question is, is it true that:

- Let *-∞-Grpd be the category of based infinity groupoids and let $S¹ : $∞$-Grpd$ be the one sphere. The construction above involving B gives a left adjoint from *-∞-Grpd to $Ω$-spectra sending wedge product to smash product. For each left adjoint $Φ$ from *-∞-Grpd to a complete monoidal closed category $C$ in which $ΦS¹$ is invertible under tensor up to isomorphism, and sending wedge product to smash product up to isomorphism, there is a unique left adjoint up to natural transformation from Ω-spectra producing a commutative diagram.

The above is to be understood as up to isomorphism and natural isomorphism where appropriate.

Comment: Not all CW-complexes can be infinitely delooped.  On the other hand, every infinite loop space gives rise to a connective spectrum, and vice-versa.  Your question is also unclear to me: you mention "left adjoint" several times - left adjoint to *what*?